# Keep wrapped flex items on left while others centred

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm trying to display a list of flex items with fixed width in the center of flexbox with wrap by using `margin: auto`. When wrap happens, the wrapped item also centers in its own container:

[image]

Is there a way to keep the wrapped item on the left while everything else is centred?

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: 100px;
}

.children {
  flex: 1;
  border: 1px solid black;
  max-width: 300px;
  min-width: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="children"></div>
  <div class="children"></div>
  <div class="children"></div>
  <div class="children"></div>
  <div class="children"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're saying you want the items centered, but when there is only one item that wraps, you want it left-aligned.

The problem is that there is really no left-alignment in the flex container. Everything is centered, based on available space in the row. So the single item in the last row has no concept of what's going on above, and nothing to align with.

Here's what happens if you left-align the last item (on wider screens):

[image]

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.children {
  border: 1px solid black;
  max-width: 300px;
  min-width: 300px;
  margin: auto;
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: 1rem;
}

.children:last-child {
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="children"></div>
  <div class="children"></div>
  <div class="children"></div>
  <div class="children"></div>
  <div class="children"></div>
</div>
```

What you need is a nested grid structure.

A top-level grid to establish the centering.

A nested grid for the wrapping.

In the demo below, you'll find a three-column grid. The left and right columns are empty (spacer) items, created with CSS pseudo-elements, and set to equal widths. This centers the middle item.

The middle item is also a grid container. Using the `repeat()` and `auto-fill` functions, the items can wrap, with individual items aligning left.

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr auto;
}

body::before,
body::after {
  content: ''; /* in grid (and flex) layouts, pseudo-elements on the container
                  are treated as items */
}

.parent {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, 300px);
  grid-auto-rows: 100px;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  justify-content: center; /* centers the columns (not the items, like in flex) */
}

.children {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="children"></div>
  <div class="children"></div>
  <div class="children"></div>
  <div class="children"></div>
  <div class="children"></div>
</div>
```

### [jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/5rscfLn8/1/)